# PHP 5.1.6. json_decode slow

Tags: php, json

Because PHP 5.1.6. doesn't include the json_decode function, I've downloaded an alternative and included it myself. But for some reason it's really really slow.

This one for example I tried:
http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps

I have tried a few other alternatives.

Does somebody know a better alternative to decode json faster or is it impossible in PHP < 5.2

Comment: How slow is slow exactly...?

Comment: Side note: PHP 5.1.6 died many years ago http://php.net/eol.php You should not use it, it has unfixed security issues.

Comment: for example a json_decode that takes a few seconds on the test servers. Takes like a minute on the server with php 5.1.6

Comment: Try https://boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html or http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/17166.html or http://pecl.php.net/package/json or https://code.google.com/archive/p/simplejson-php/

Comment: In all honesty you should consider upgrading to PHP 5.2 since PHP 5.1's EOL was so long ago. Any custom PHP extension or class which you find is very unlikely to be well maintained at this point since PHP has a native solution. Look at http://php.net/manual/en/migration52.php and specifically read into the Backwards Incompatible Changes for the greatest chance of success with minimal errors.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look in to the possibilities. Its not my server so I dont know if I can get them to upgrade it :)